# How to echo a set of variables with on a new line?

Tags: echo

How to print set of variables in one line and next set in new line?

Example:

```
echo $uname $uid $fullname $homedirectory
```

as

```
bob 1 bobby /sbin
max 2 maxwell /bin
```

I tried using \n at the end but it is giving new line for every variable like this

```
bob
1
bobby
/sbin
max
2
maxwell
/bin
```

But how to have \n at the end of set of variables?

Answer (score 1):

Using `echo` with `-e` does what you are looking for

```
$ echo -e $HOME'\n'$HOME'\n'$HOME
/home/user
/home/user
/home/user
```

A simple `man echo` is your friend

Comment: i am trying get group of variables in same line and next set in another line. Like a table.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $uname $uid $fullname $homedirectory;echo
```

by just calling another echo w/o an argument, it will print a new line at the end of the previously printed line with the variables.

I don't see a reason you couldn't just use,

```
printf  "$uname $uid $fullname $homedirectory\n"
```

instead, which is another member of coreutils.  I know this doesn't fix the problem with echo, but it should give you the output you desire!

Comment: can you tell me which version of echo you are using?

Comment: also check to make sure you aren't aliasing the echo command to mean something other than regular echo, you can check this in your ~/.bachrc or ~/.bash_profile

Comment: this the echo version echo (GNU coreutils) 5.97

Comment: I would try updating coreutils, I think i'm using version 7.4 on my linux box at home.  Other than that, using printf might be your best bet in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

change `#!/usr/sh` to `#!/usr/bash` if you are running it inside a script.

Answer (score 0):

You may Add this separator:

```
echo nl2br("\n");

<?php
$uname="bob";
$uid="1";
$fullname="bobby";
$homedirectory="/sbin";
echo $uname ." ".  $uid  ." ". $fullname ." ".  $homedirectory;
echo nl2br("\n");
$uname="max";
$uid="2";
$fullname="maxwell";
$homedirectory="/bin";
echo $uname  ." ". $uid  ." ". $fullname  ." ". $homedirectory;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple echo command for this.

```
echo $uname."<br>".$uid."<br>".$fullname."<br>".$homedirectory."<br>";
```